# Jetlag - sleep or nap and delay sleep until destination time

Tags: jet-lag

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I avoid or minimize jet lag?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/1014/how-can-i-avoid-or-minimize-jet-lag)

I am flying to London from Sydney. While still in Sydney, is it better to have a nap and delay my sleeping until London time says its okay, or to stick with Sydney time until I get on the plane?

The specific situation is as follow. Half an hour ago, it was 12:00 in London, but 21:00 in Sydney. We will be catching a plane at 06:00 Sydney time (need to be awake at 03:00 to get there) and arriving in London at 20:15. My older brother decided to go to bed at 10:00 and to sleep to 3:00. As he normally sleeps about 11:30, this moves him an hour and a half the wrong way. I decided that I'll have a nap between about 22:00 to 00:00 and then try to get some sleep on the plane (which will be about 21:00 London time). Which of these strategies do you think would be better with dealing with jet lag?

Comment: @Andra: Its not the same question - but a more more specific version!

Comment: ...which is still covered by the answers - eg the ones which talk about stretching your day etc.  In addition asking 'which do you think' invites discussion, which we try to avoid (see [faq]).  This would be a good ones to discuss in the [chat] as it currently stands - but if you'd like to rephrase your question to distinguish it as *different* (not just more or less specific) then we could answer it happily.

Comment: @Mark Answering a general question doesn't  cover every more specific question